# Developer at my company tells me Apache has nothing to do with serving GZIP'd content

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, webserver, gzip

I'd like a second opinion as what i'm being told contradicts everything i'm reading.

I have a Wordpress site running on an Apache server. I want to enable GZIP compression. I have not been successful in doing so via Wordpress plugins, so I want to try it via adding the appropriate lines to .htaccess. I am being told I should not do this, and that Wordpress should "be responsible for creating the GZIP files".

This sounds wrong to me and I would like some input. Thanks!

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_deflate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instincts are correct, what you have been told is wrong. Apache can handle GZIP compression with no issues.

Please see the .htaccess instructions here:
https://technumero.com/gzip-compression-in-wordpress/